# Java move private function into setter

Tags: java

I have the following code. Is there a way to avoid writing a separate private method and have this logic embedded in the .tests setter (I am using Lombok's builder).

```
    public TestResponse build(Map<String, List<TestRequest> testRequestMap) {

        return TestResponseBuilder.builder()
                .tests(getTestResponses(testRequestMap))
                .build();
    }

     private List<Test> getTestResponses(Map<String, List<TestRequest> testRequestMap) {

       List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();
       testRequestMap.keySet().stream().forEach( t -> {
           Test test = new Test();
           test.setTest(t);
           tests.add(test);
       });
       return test;
   }
```

Thanks
Ram

Comment: It's hard to make a judgment without seeing what `// logic to build tests` involves. Provided `getTestResponses` has a single statement, returning the value, sure: just inline into the `build` method.

Comment: What do you think will you gain by that? What is your motivation to change this?

Comment: @AndyTurner added the code logic

Comment: @AndyTurner Added the logic to build tests. I have quite a few responses like these to build. Was trying to see if I can build this inline to make the code look better. Hence raised this question.

Comment: @AndyTurner quick question - how is it possible to inline this function into the setter? I am not sure on the syntax. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, you can't, because you have more than one statement in the method.

However, you can write it as:

```
return testRequestMap.keySet().stream()
    .map(t -> {
       Test test = new Test();
       test.setTest(t);
       return test;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This can then be inlined directly into the `.tests(...)` method call as a parameter.

```
    return TestResponseBuilder.builder()
            .tests(
                testRequestMap.keySet().stream()
                        .map(t -> {
                           Test test = new Test();
                           test.setTest(t);
                           return test;
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .build();
```

but really, this is worse than what you currently have.

Comment: thank you very much  this is what I was looking for. I see the point. I will stick to my existing implementation as it looks cleaner. Thanks for the guidance.